# Scaling (or rotation) object using two random points (helpers, vertexes for ex.)

Tags: scale

The thing is there is an object. I wanna pick a first point anywhere on object to make it a pivot point for scale (or rotation), and pick another point (empty object or vertex of this object) which I will grab then, and by moving this second point in space the object will rotate and scale.
Some 3D-applications have this feature.

[image]

Here's another image with a task for better understading. For that task object should be rotated, positioned and scaled, while this points changes their destinations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can set the pivot point to be the cursor or the active vertice in edit mode. You rotate normally R r double R tho, not grabbing from a specific point. But it should give a similar result

Comment: Yes, but I wanna the second (grabbing) point to snap to some other points (like vertex for example). With just rotatle i cannot snap my cursor to anything. And mostly i wanna object to scale while i move second point.

Comment: You want the object to scale uniformly? Or only in the direction to the snap?

Comment: Scale like in parenting one object to another, but only using some kind of line, which points i can change (not just scale the line) and the object will transform accordingly.